# ColdFusion Caching Solutions for Fusebox 4

Tags: caching, coldfusion, methodology

I have an application that was built using Fusebox 4 with ColdFusion. Can anyone recommend a good caching solution, that is a plugin, which works directly with this older version of the framework?

Another idea I've been tinkering around with is to take the most commonly used queries in the system and applying `cachedWithin`. The value would be a variable stored in the application scope. Basically anytime we update any of the most commonly accessed tables in the db, we update the `application.cachedwithin` variable as well. So whenever these tables are updated the data is refreshed. Anything else that isn't used frequently will simply query the DB to get the content.

Also to add to this very simple caching methodology would be to simply store strings, or other frequently used content, directly within the application scope.

This bulk of this application is around 30 pages, comprised of approximately 200 products. So its quite a small website.

Can anyone recommend a good Fusebox 4 cache plugin or confirm if this simple caching methodology is a good idea? If not, could you recommend a simple alternative? 
thanks in advance

Comment: what version of CF are you using?  CF9+ has more flexible ehCache for caching data (e.g. query) or page content.  Older version has cfcache and basic query cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [cfcache](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d5a.html) to store all pages output into statistics HTML files.

Then on any update, you can clear the cache of the updated pages or all the cache:

```
<cfcache action="flush" />
<cfobjectcache action="clear" />
```

make sure to disable the urlSessionFormat() in URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you even need to be caching given the size of the site, unless you are getting a huge amount of traffic.  If you are currently having performance problems, the first thing to do is make sure that Fusebox is in production mode, so that it isn't recreating the parsed files on each request.

Caching the queries should certainly aid performance - how long are the queries currently taking to execute? With Fusebox 4, it can be problematic to have "Report execution times" turned on in CF when debugging, as it can significantly affect the time the request takes to execute.